# Keep width while using position: fixed

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to keep the width of a div when using position fixed, the fixed div has an extra width

```css
.col-1 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 58px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.fixed {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1">Test</div>
<div class="col-1 fixed">Test</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Maybe `position: sticky` instead of `fixed` works for what you want to do?

Comment: left:0 ........

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` to the `.fixed` div to achieve 100% width

```
.fixed {
     z-index: 9999;
     position: fixed;
     background-color: red;
     margin-top: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
}
```

This won't look exactly the same due to the first div having `margin` applied to it coming from the `<body>`, giving it the white space you see around it. I'd advise removing that margin using a reset to achieve the same width.

An example:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Of course if the margin was intended to be there you can set the `left` and `right` to match whatever that is, in this case `8px`.